# How to Convert a vector string to simple string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to convert a string vector in a simple string. I do not know how to proceed.
I tried various solutions such as

```
for(int i=1; i < easy.length; i++){

easyPuzzle = easy[i].toString();

}

System.out.println(" " + easyPuzzle);
```

but this solution prints only the ith element and not the entire string vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You keep reassign a new value to `easyPuzzle` when you really want to concatenate:

```
easyPuzzle += easy[i].toString();
```

If `easy.length` is large, it might make sense to use a StringBuilder which is more efficient at concatenating than String:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=1; i < easy.length; i++){
    builder.append(easy[i].toString());
}
easyPuzzle = builder.toString();
```

Also by starting your for loop at `i=1` you exclude the first item. Not sure if it is on purpose or not. If not, start at `i = 0`.

Alternatively, to save the pain of writing the loop yourself, you can use [@Manoj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308095/829571) which replaces your code by one line.

Answer (score 9):

Use toString in [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) class

```
Arrays.toString(easy);
```

Comment: +1, note that in case of more than 1-dimensional arrays better to use `Arrays.deepToString(a)`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to you use `StringBuilder` with `append(<data>)` method and then convert it to `String`.

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 1; i < easy.length; i++){
    data.append(easy[i].toString());
}
easyPuzzle = data.toString();
```

`String` is immutable so work with it is much more consume. When you work with `String`, i recommend to you use `StringBuilder`, is more effective and faster.

**Update:** @Manoj answer is very usefull.